# Syntactic binding value must be a keyword: alpha. What does it mean?

Tags: lisp, scheme, mit-scheme

Here is my little program:

```
(let-syntax ((alpha (lambda (x)
                      (list (syntax quote)
                            (list)))))
  (alpha))
```

And guile executes it, and returns (). But mit-scheme outputs the following:

```
;Syntactic binding value must be a keyword: alpha
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.
```

Why?

(my version is: Release 9.1 || Microcode 15.3 || Runtime 15.7 || SF 4.41 || LIAR/i386 4.118 || Edwin 3.116)

Comment: What are you trying to do, here?  Why is there no **syntax-rules** keyword?  Are you sure you want to use **let-syntax** and not one of the regular versions of **let**?

Comment: Yes it is done intentionally. I'm studying the low level scheme macro expansion mechanismes. Actually I read this page: http://www.cs.indiana.edu/scheme-repository/R4RS/r4rs_12.html

Comment: But you're misusing the mechanism; there's no transformer spec there.  What do you hope to achieve?

Comment: The (lambda (x) ...)  is the transformer, which accepts the syntax object x, and returns a syntax object '(#<syntax quote> ()). It is a simplification of one of the syntax usage examples from that URL, i posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MIT Scheme only provides `syntax-rules`, syntactic closures, and explicit renaming for defining syntax transformers. For the latter two, you want either `sc-macro-transformer` or the `er-macro-transformer` forms. If you want to use syntax objects, you'll need to use an implementation that supports syntax objects (which usually comes with `syntax-case`) such as [Racket](http://www.racket-lang.org) or [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/).

By the way, even in a language with syntax objects your macro definition may not work because you're returning a list from your transformer instead of syntax. Also, the web page you linked to is a pretty old standard. You might want to read a more recent source on macros, such as [TSPL4](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you linked to demonstrates explicitly that you absolutely must use syntax-rules with let-syntax. Here is the exact syntactic contract.

```
    <macro block> ==>
          (let-syntax (<syntax spec>*) <body>)
         | (letrec-syntax (<syntax spec>*) <body>)
    <syntax spec> ==> (<keyword> <transformer spec>)
    <transformer spec> ==>
          (syntax-rules (<identifier>*) <syntax rule>*)
```

In accordance with the specifications, using anything other than syntax-rules cannot be expected to run without error. The only reason this generates an error in MIT Scheme and not in Guile is because of MIT Scheme's more prolific application of exceptions (that is, MIT Scheme's let-syntax specifically looks to ensure you gave it syntax-rules). It is simply not valid R4RS code, and shouldn't work in any R4RS compatible Scheme implementation.